# Android SipDemo app. SipException: Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable

Tags: android, sip

I have downloaded SipDemo app from official [repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SipDemo/). I ran the app and made SIP calls from my phone. But I want to integrate SIP calls into my own app. I copied code from SipDemo app into my own project, ran a project. When I want to make a SIP call I get an error:

> 21319-21319/com.app.myapplication I/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall﹕ Error when trying to close manager.
>       android.net.sip.SipException: Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable?
>               at android.net.sip.SipManager.createSipSession(SipManager.java:555)
>               at android.net.sip.SipManager.makeAudioCall(SipManager.java:328)
>               at android.net.sip.SipManager.makeAudioCall(SipManager.java:359)
>               at com.tickets.myapplication.WalkieTalkieActivity.initiateCall(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:221)
>               at com.tickets.myapplication.WalkieTalkieActivity$5.onClick(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:332)
>               at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I don't know why this error happens and how to fix it. Does someone know what is the reason of this error?

**EDIT**
Finally I have found problem. SipDemo app uses `targetSdkVersion 9` in my project I use latest android version. Seems problem in the newest version of `android.net.sip.SipManager`.

Comment: The [demo manifest](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/SipDemo/AndroidManifest.xml) does **not** ask for `targetSdkVersion 9`, but rather specifies `minSdkVersion 9`.

Comment: @snd Yes you are correct. `targetSdkVersion 9` automatically set by Android Studio when import project into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to create library project with `targetSdkVersion 9` and add dependency to working project. Now it works ok for me.